# a generalization of a formula of Shimura

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, l-functions

Let $\phi$ be a $GL(2)$ automorphic form with Fourier coefficients $a(n)$ and $a(1)=1$.
Obviously we have $L(s,\phi)=\sum \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$.

Shimura have the following formula
$L(s, Ad\; \phi)=\zeta(2s)\sum\frac{a(n^2)}{n^s}$. [*]

I would like to see its generalization to $GL(3)$ or $GL(N)$.
Let $\phi$ be a $GL(3)$ automorphic form with Fourier coefficients $a(m,n)$ and $a(1,1)=1$.
We have $L(s,\phi)=\sum \frac{a(1,n)}{n^s}$.
I would like to know a formula for $L(s, Ad\; \phi)$ like [*].

We shall note that we always have $L(s,Ad\;\phi)=L(s,\phi \times \overline{\phi})/\zeta(s)$ but that is not what I want.

Comment: The $n^2$ in Shimura's formula suggests half-integer weight forms are involved, so maybe there is something similar involving the metaplectic double cover of $GL(3)$?

Comment: Shimura's formula is only valid for square-free level and trivial nebentypus. For the coefficients of $L(s,\phi \times \overline{\phi})$ there is a suitable formula, see Definition 12.1.1 in Goldfeld's Automorphic forms and L-functions for the group GL(n,R). Convolving these with the Möbius function gives the coefficients you need. In the case of $n=2$ the coefficients are pretty because $a(p^k)^2-a(p^{k-1})^2=a(p^{2k})$ for $p$ prime.